# Sublime Text 3 Menu Bar gone

Tags: sublime-text-3

I accidentally hid the menu bar of my Sublime Text 3 Editor on Ubuntu 18.04. Haven't found an option to show it again. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution [here](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/solved-how-to-show-the-menu-back/2020/4).

1. Close sublime text
2. Go to /home/-user-/.config/sublime-text-version-/Local/
3. Change every “menu_visible”:false to “menu_visible”:true
4. Save the file
5. Reopen sublime text

Answer (score 3):

Press the alt key, menu will appear and when it does go to View and choose Hide/Show Menu menu entry